# Replace comma between words in excel with quote and close with square braces

Tags: excel, replace

I'm trying to do following:

`excel cell = bread,milk,butter,jam,juice,coffee`
`intended cell = ["bread" "milk" "butter" "jam" "juice" "coffee"]`

Is there a formula or tool I can use within excel to convert `excel cell` to `intended cell`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following formula.

```
="[" & CHAR(34) & SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(34) & " " & CHAR(34)) & CHAR(34) & "]"
```

[image]